# How can I empty log files with a cron job on WSL?

Tags: bash, log, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Where is the log directory in WSL?

There seems to be no such directory as `/var/log/`.

My aim is to run this *nix cron daily command:

```
0 0 * * * cat /dev/null > /var/mail/* /var/log/*
```

Comment: There is a /var/log in WSL. But you can't use a directory as stdout. What do you want to do with your daily command?

Comment: The command would be `rm -r /var/mail/* /var/log/*` but I am not so sure if this is a good idea.

Comment: Redirecting to a list of files (and directories in your case, as /var/log contains subdirectories) will not work. You could use `find /var/log -type f -exec > {} \;` to empty all files in /var/log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/var/log` is at `/var/log` (at least in the version 16.04.3 LTS that I just installed in my Windows system).

```
$ ls -l /var/log
total 304
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root    512 Sep 22 18:15 apt
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp      0 Sep 22 18:15 btmp
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root    512 Jul 19 01:29 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12794 Sep 22 18:15 dpkg.log
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root    512 Sep 22 18:13 fsck
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 292292 Jan 14 19:58 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x 0 root root    512 Aug 23 04:06 lxd
drwxr-x--- 0 root adm     512 Aug  1 04:46 unattended-upgrades
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp      0 Sep 22 18:15 wtmp
```

But you won't be able to redirect your output to a list of files and subdirectories (as I told you in the comments).

You can empty all log files by the following cronjob (for root):

`find /var/log -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;`

Comment: Sure, input cannot be redirected to a directory but to a file in a directory. I need to ask your apologize, I confused the `/var/log` dir (which is available it my WSL also) with a file - I treated it as if it were a file. I can indeed do `rm -rf`, for example, to remove these directories even though a sysadmin recommended me to redirect `/dev/null` into the files inside them. Something I really wish to do.

Comment: Your `find` command won't work the way you think it will. `>` will be handled by the shell before `find` is started, so the command executed will be `find /var/log -type f -exec echo -n \;` with the entire stdout redirected to a file named `{}`. You probably want something like `-exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` or `-exec sh -c 'echo -n > "$1"' _ {} \;`

Comment: @muclux ah, looks like I edited my comment after you saw it, it should be `truncate -s 0 {} \;` (Sorry!)

Comment: @muru My fault, I should have verified how truncate works (I didn't know this command).

Comment: Thanks both of you. In the end I used `find /var/mail/* /var/log/* -type f -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;` based on your example, @muclux.